# How can smooth scroll be triggered using onsroll event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onscroll

For the past few weeks I've been trying to get my website to scroll like this page [see here](https://www.tesla.com/models). All my research has only shown methods doing this with anchors, but I don't want this event to work off a button click. I want to do this like the page I provided where this works off a scrolling event.

I've tried this:

```
render() {
    var scrollPos = 0
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      scrollPos = window.scrollTop
      let height = window.screen.availHeight
      let lastScrollPos = scrollPos
      if (lastScrollPos >= scrollPos) {window.scrollBy(0, height)} else {window.scrollBy(0, -height)}
    })
```

This seems to only get my scrollbar stuck. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Maybe via a react package but I would like to know how I could create this effect myself.